# SIGSTOP on C: Invalid Argument

Tags: c, system-calls

I have this code. The problem is that SIGSTOP give me on perror "Invalid Argument". I have to wait SIGCONT from parent before Child1 and Child2 can continue, but I can't do because of this. How can I solve?

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int pid1=0;
int pid2=0;

if((pid1=fork())==0) { //Child1

    if(signal(SIGSTOP, SIG_DFL)==SIG_ERR) perror("P1: Error SIGSTOP: ");
    if(signal(SIGCONT, SIG_DFL)==SIG_ERR) perror("P1: Error SIGCONT: ");
    pause();

    printf("P1: I can continue.\n");

} else if((pid2=fork())==0) { //Child2

    if(signal(SIGSTOP, SIG_DFL)==SIG_ERR) perror("P2: Error SIGSTOP: ");
    if(signal(SIGCONT, SIG_DFL)==SIG_ERR) perror("P2: Error SIGCONT: ");
    pause();

    printf("P2: I can continue.\n");

} else { //Parent

    printf("G: PID: %d\n", getpid());

    kill(pid1, SIGSTOP);
    kill(pid2, SIGSTOP); 

    //Some work
    
    kill(pid1, SIGCONT);
    kill(pid2, SIGCONT);

    wait(0); wait(0);

    exit(0);

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The signal `SIGSTOP` (the same for `SIGKILL`) can't be caught or its disposition changed - which you're attempting to do.

You just need to get rid of the `signal(SIGSTOP, SIG_DFL)` calls.

From [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.